# new column base on existing column values

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, conditional-statements, nan

Trying to create a new values `Chill` or `Frozen` base on existing column "Temp" values.

The `Temp` contains values like:

```
-18.00C
-20.00C
+10.00C
+19.00C
Nan
DRY
```

How can implement it using Pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': ['-18.00C', '+10.00c', 'NaN', 'DRY']})
```

If the `Temp` is < 0.0C, it will fall under `Frozen`
If the `Temp` is > 0.0C, it will fall under `Chill`
If the `Temp` is "Nan" or "DRY", it will fall under `NA`

Expected Results:

```
Temp_Category
Frozen
Chill
NA
NA
```

Comment: What happen if value is `0` ? there is always `+` before positive values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract first value and [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dictionary, but always necessary values `+` and `-` before numbers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': ['-18.00C', '+10.00c', 'NaN', 'DRY', '+0c', '20c']})

d = {'-':'Frozen', '+':'Chill'}
df['new1'] = df['Temp'].str[0].map(d)
```

Another idea is extract numeric value, convert to `float` and use [`numpy.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) but if there is `0` output is `0` too, so output is `NaN`:

```
pat = r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)"
d1 = {1:'Chill', -1:'Frozen', 0:'Chill'}
df['new2'] = np.sign(df['Temp'].str.extract(pat, expand=False).astype(float)).map(d1)
```

Solution with `2` conditions and [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
pat = r"([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+)"
s = df['Temp'].str.extract(pat).astype(float)
df['new3'] = np.select([s >= 0, s < 0], ['Chill','Frozen'], default=np.nan)
```

And if only last value in temperature is non numeric (e.g. `c` or `C`) is possible use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with remove last character by indexing:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Temp'].str[:-1], errors='coerce')
df['new4'] = np.select([s >= 0, s < 0], ['Chill','Frozen'], default=np.nan)
print (df)
      Temp    new1    new2    new3    new4
0  -18.00C  Frozen  Frozen  Frozen  Frozen
1  +10.00c   Chill   Chill   Chill   Chill
2      NaN     NaN     NaN     nan     nan
3      DRY     NaN     NaN     nan     nan
4      +0c   Chill   Chill   Chill   Chill
5      20c     NaN   Chill   Chill   Chill
```